# Implications for COM Interfaces that don't inherit from IUnknown

Tags: c++, ms-word, com, idl, iunknown

I am trying to implement some COM interfaces that can be used while [exporting Word documents as PDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/extend-the-fixed-format-export-feature-in-word-automation-services). Some of these interfaces don't inherit from `IUnknown`, for instance:

```
#undef  INTERFACE
#define INTERFACE  IMsoServerFileManagerSite
DECLARE_INTERFACE(IMsoServerFileManagerSite)
{
  STDMETHOD_(BOOL, FGetHandle) (const WCHAR *pwzFileName, HANDLE *phFile, BOOL fRead, BOOL fWrite) PURE;
  STDMETHOD_(BOOL, FCloseHandle) (HANDLE hFile) PURE;
};
```

I found that I can translate these interfaces to IDL if I use the [local](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/midl/local) attribute (declaring that they aren't remote). For instance

```
[
    local,
    uuid(f8e47685-e402-4119-aa07-4ea4ff1f1123)
]
interface IMsoServerFileManagerSite
{
    BOOL FGetHandle(const WCHAR *pwzFileName, HANDLE *phFile, BOOL fRead, BOOL fWrite);
    BOOL FCloseHandle(HANDLE hFile);
}
```

Another such interface, `IMsoDocExporter`, does inherit from `IUnknown`, but has some functions that return `void` rather than `HRESULT`. When I pass an object implementing this interface to the Word API I can attach a debugger and see that my dll is being called by functions like `combase.dll!CRemoteUnknown::RemQueryInterface`.

So my questions are:

1. Does `combase.dll!CRemoteUnknown::RemQueryInterface` mean that my object is being queried remotely? (i.e. I'll need a proxy/stub, and can't use the `[local]` attr?)
2. if an interface uses non-automation types, such as `HANDLE`, and doesn't return an `HRESULT` can it still be marshalled?
3. is there a way/what is the best way to translate these interfaces to IDL so that MIDL will provide the proxy/stub implementation? (e.g. MIDL reference suggested that [call_as](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/midl/call-as) could be used to map these functions to remote callable functions -- still unclear what I could do with `HANDLE` though)

Comment: A COM object must implement the `IUnknown` interface.

Comment: generally yes, but these interfaces don't (they are from Microsoft, so presumably it's not a mistake). To quote from the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/extend-the-fixed-format-export-feature-in-word-automation-services) in my post: "_This interface does not inherit from IUnknown. Accordingly, the fixed-format export DLL is allowed to keep a reference to it for its lifetime._"

Comment: do you have to treat them as COM? I also notice that `the service runs in a highly restricted environment without access to most places in the file system` so are you sure it can even contact a server process?

Comment: I don't think the service has to contact anything because it just provides `IMsoDocExporter*` and then the Word application is querying that interface (from another thread/process perhaps).

Comment: If it doesn't inherit from IUnknown it's not a COM interface.

Comment: Where are these interface (like IMsoServerFileManagerSite) declared? what SDK? file?

Comment: Good question, I've been searching for an official resource. [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338206(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) says that the interfaces are defined in fixedformatext.h, but so far I only managed to find [this forum post](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?846465-How-to-use-IMsoDocExporter-interface-of-ExportAsFixedFormat) where someone has uploaded that header. It seems to be accurate though.

Answer (score 1):

After some more playing around I finally managed to make it work. @molbdnilo and @Jonathan Potter were correct. Only the `IMsoDocExporter` interface is a COM object, and it inherits from `IUnknown`. The other interfaces are just plain vtables I suppose and it seems that they can't be marshalled (at least not without writing lots of custom proxy/stub code).

> 1. Does combase.dll!CRemoteUnknown::RemQueryInterface mean that my object is being queried remotely?

Yes, but this only applied to `IMsoDocExporter` (the actual COM object)

> 2. if an interface uses non-automation types, such as HANDLE, and doesn't return an HRESULT can it still be marshalled?

It turns out yes. As mentioned in my original post you can mark these methods `[local]` and then define a similar method with the `[call_as]` attribute that returns `HRESULT` and has RPC-able parameters. Then you just need to define the functions that translates one call to the other. Ultimately, to marshal a `HANDLE` you need to specify the type information.